# ERR.NGHP-DISTRIBUTION.INTERNAL_ERROR

Tags: sabre

with test credentials Get Hotel Avail API version 3 and 4 both not working it showing the errorCode ERR.NGHP-DISTRIBUTION.INTERNAL_ERROR
and errorMessage Error occurred while invoking service restish:convertToOutputFormat:1.64.0

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by missing header information. The following line needs to be added to the request when building your Rest2SgRequest:

```
request.setHeaders("{\"Accept\": \"application/json\"}");
```